# Autoconfiguration replace imported services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

When I import services in the main configuration:

```yaml
imports:
    - { resource: services/attribute_loaders.yaml }
```

The services in the included file will be replaced with an autoconfigured version, so I've missed all my configured tags:

```yaml
services:
  App\Infrastructure\Bridge\Doctrine\EventListener\AttributeLoader\OrderAttributeLoader:
    autowire: true
    tags:
      - name: 'doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener'
        entity: 'App\Infrastructure\Bridge\Doctrine\EventListener\AttributeLoader\OrderAttributeLoader'
        event: 'postLoad'
```

As a workaround, I've excluded my service from autoconfigure.

Is there any way to decompose services into several files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how you do it.

If you are going to use multiple files to configure your services, you simply can't define the same service twice.

Your definitions need to be specific enough so they do not overlap.

If you are going to use broad `resource` settings, you will need to add all the corresponding excludes so services defined in different files are not defined before it's time:

```yaml
services:
  App\:
     resource: '../src/*'
     exclude:
       - '../src/Infrastructure/Symfony/DependencyInjection'
       - '../src/Infrastructure/Symfony/Kernel.php'
       - '../src/Tests'
       - '../src/Messenger'
```

Services on `src/Messenger`, that belong to the `App\Messenger` namespace, can be defined independently on a different file:

E.g. something like this:

```yaml
# messenger_services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false

    
    App\Messenger\CommandHandler\:
        resource: '../../src/Messenger/CommandHandler/*'
        tags:
          - {name: 'messenger.message_handler', bus: command.bus}

    App\Messenger\EventHandler\:
        resource: '../../src/Application/EventHandler/*'
        tags:
          - {name: 'messenger.message_handler', bus: event.bus}
```